# Using SharedPreferences between activities

Tags: android, android-preferences

My app is based around a DashboardActivity. Another activity is called News.

In this News activity, I load information from the internet using an AsyncTask. The user can navigate away from this activity and start others, and I would like to download the information only **once** in the duration of the app's life cycle.

That is, what I want is:

- User starts app, goes to News, information is downloaded.
- App remembers that the info has been downloaded, so if News is started again, the information will not be downloaded.
- When the app is stopped (let's say user presses back button from main activity), the app must "forget" that the info had been downloaded. So next time the app is started, the info must be downloaded again when News is started.

I thought about doing this with SharedPreferences.

Here's what it looks like in News:

```
int news_loaded = 0;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
static SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ....
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    news_loaded = preferences.getInt("news_loaded", 2);

    <<start asynctask here>>
}
```

In the `doInBackground` of the AsyncTask:

```
if(news_loaded == 0)
    <<download info>>
```

In the `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask (if info was downloaded only):

```
editor.putInt("news_loaded", 1);
editor.commit();
```

Here's the `onStop` method of the DashboardActivity:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
static SharedPreferences preferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

protected void onStop()
{
    preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("news_loaded", 0);
    editor.commit();
    super.onStop();
}
```

Problem: the `news_loaded` always seems to be 0 when I start the News activity.

---

### Update

This is the manifest part of DashboardActivity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".DashboardActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

It seems that `onStop()` (and `onDestroy()`) are called each time I press the back button - no matter "how far in" I am in different activities.

Comment: Have you tried moving it to your onDestroy()-method? I think I had a similar problem once. Even if you navigate away from your activity and open up another one onStop() will be called but not onDestroy()

Comment: @Duzi Doesn't seem to be doing the trick I'm afraid.

Comment: Oh, ok. So maybe you should use a static boolean then, which is false by default. As soon as your start the App you set the value to true. That's how you can make sure that while you are in your app the news are only downloaded once

Comment: I don't see why this should work - using a boolean instead of an int. And I've just tried: result is the same.

Comment: Use it like I said, as a static value and not as Preference. You have a static class which has a static boolean value. When your app starts you set this value to true. Static values "live" through your entire runtime.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be working! Thanks for clarifying. Only 1 problem now, however: When I exit the app (press back button) and open it again "from scratch" and go to the News activity - the boolean is still true. If I kill the app entirely by using another app (task killer), the value will be false when I open the app again. How to solve this?

Comment: You could try to set the value to false again on onRestart() or onResume()

Comment: @Duzi Thanks for your help, I managed to get it to work :) Please leave an answer for +rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should use a static boolean, which is false by default. As soon as your start the App you set the value to true. That's how you can make sure that while you are in your app the news are only downloaded once. Static values "live" through your entire runtime. Set the value to false again on onRestart() or onResume() ;)